# Heroku destroy_all 1/2 million rows seems to hang

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres

On Heroku with Postgres

In the Heroku console when I do SiteInfo.destroy_all it just seems to hang. There are 1/2 million rows. What would be the best way to destroy these rows? Should I just do a migration to drop the table and then recreate it?

As per the comments be careful of you have callbacks. I do not. I just need to get rid of all these rows in the table fast and easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE site_infos")
```

This will occur extremely quick in comparison to `destroy_all` as `destroy_all` loops through each record.

Comment: Perfection. Worked in milliseconds.

Comment: Could be bad if you are counting on callback or dependant destroy functionality. Could always do SiteInfo.find_each.map { |si| si.destroy }

Comment: @penner, this is true. However, since OP was contemplating dropping the table and then recreating it, I assumed that callbacks were not part of the requirements.

Comment: Agreed, the answer is good. Just leaving this for the Googlers.